# Spring MVC GET request with Java 8 Instant request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, java.time.instant

I'm trying to write a Spring MVC GET controller that takes a Java 8 Instant as request parameter:

```
    @GetMapping
    @JsonView(OrderListing.class)
    @Validated
    public WebSeekPaginatedResultsDto<OrderListingDto> findAll(@Valid OrderSearchCommand orderSearchCommand) {
       // Some code
    }
```

with:

```
    public class OrderSearchCommand {
        private Instant dateCreatedStart;
        private Instant dateCreatedEnd;
        // Some other fields
    }
```

I'm triggering a GET request from some React/Javascript code with something like that:

```
    http://localhost:8080/mms/front/orders?dateCreatedStart=2017-05-31T22%3A00%3A00.000Z
```

Spring does not seem to like it and throws an error. Here is the error message:

```
    Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Instant' for property 'dateCreatedStart'; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Instant' for property 'dateCreatedStart': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any idea why I'm getting this?

Thank you

Comment: The parameter you are receiving is of type `String` and you are trying to store it in an `Instant`. You must convert `String` to `Instant`.

Comment: You must annotate the fields with `@DateTimeFormat` as shown in the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40940615/5221149).

Comment: If `Instant` does not work with the "duplicate" post, take a look at section 9.5 in the spring reference (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert) .  Section 9.5.5 covers registration of your custom converter.

Comment: @Andreas I reopened the question because, I believe that, `@DateTimeFormat` does not work with `Instant`.  `Instant` is not listed in the supported types for this annotation in the Spring 4 reference document.

Comment: @DwB Ahh, I just looked at javadoc of [`DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html), which said *"JSR-310 `java.time` types"*, but you are right, the source code of [`Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.java#L51) only lists 6 types: LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime, OffsetDateTime, OffsetTime.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers
Actually I've already tried `@DateTimeFormat` but it didn't work, it doesn't work with `Instant` type
I'll check the converter and see how it will go
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Error message is self-explanatory:
there is no registered `String` to `Instant` converter.

When `Controller` receives request, all parameters are `String`s. Spring/Jackson has list of predefined converter for most of basic types:
 - String > Integer
 - String > Boolean

But there is no default String > Instant converter.

You need to create and register one. Or you can change input type to something that Spring can handle with `@DateTimeFormat` annotation:
[How to accept Date params in a GET request to Spring MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: Thank you @Tim I'll check this out and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the @DateTimeFormat will not work for `Instant` fields.
Specifically,
`Instant` is not listed as one of the types for which it works in the Spring reference doc.

Check out [Spring Reference Section 9.5](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert) for details about Spring custom type conversion.
Create a `Converter<String, Instant>` converter.
Section 9.5.5 covers custom type converter registration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you? [serialize/deserialize java 8 java.time with Jackson JSON mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper) I see that this Jackson include Instant class.